# Catching a click event on an <a> hyperlink with Backbone's Events function

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, hyperlink, click

I have recently switched from using two buttons to using a dropdown list of links in my backbone model.

Previously, this code captured these button clicks:

```
events: {
        "click #expense-delete-button": "deleteRow",
        "click #expense-copy-button": "copyRow",
    },
```

This worked fine, but now that I've changed my html to this:

```
<div class ="expense-action-icons btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon-cog"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="expense-copy-button">
                <img src="../Images/copy.png"/>
                Copy Entry
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="expense-delete-button">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                Delete Entry
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The clicks are not being captured. I tried `onclick` as well and this didn't work.

Comment: Are you using e.preventDefault() in the click handlers to stop the link from being followed?

Comment: We are going to need a more complete example. There are a number of reasons this could be broken but based on what you've provided I created this http://jsfiddle.net/VpDs2/ and it works just fine... So something you have not provided is where the issue is!

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the function inside your view.

```
    events: {
        "click #expense-delete-button": "deleteRow",
        "click #expense-copy-button": "copyRow",
    },

    deleteRow:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Element clicked on
        var target =  $(e.currentTarget);
        console.log('whatever you want');
    },

    copyRow:function(e){
        //Element clicked on
        var target =  $(e.currentTarget);

        console.log('copy your row');
    },

    initialize:function(){
        //view code....
    }
```

Comment: While I don't think this solved OP's problem, I was running into a similar issue with the child element of the anchor tag propagating the event and later mistakenly calling `e.target` instead of `e.currentTarget` as demonstrated in this snippet.